# Doctrine: Get all unread notifications entities from a User entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a `Store` entity from which I can get all the notifications set for a store using a `getNotifications()` method.

I've added a field in the `Notification` entity and called it "`isRead`". It is boolean.

Now, from the `Store` entity I want to get only the unread notifications.

**Where should have I to put the method `getUnreadNotifications()`?**

UPDATE
To be more clear: if I have the store named "My Awesome Store" and this store has 10 notifications, I want to show on the page the info of the store itself and also all the 10 notifications. Those notifications have to be filtered by the field isRead, so showing only the notifications where `isRead = 0`.
So I want to select from the database only these notifications, not all notifications and then filter out the ones yet read.

The code of the controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("store/{id}", name="showStore")
 * @Template()
 * @param $id
 * @return array
 */
public function showAction($id)
{
    // Get store info
    $store = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Store')->find($id);

    ...

    // Get Orders
    $orders = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Order')->findByChannel($store->getId());

    ...

    // Check if the current user is the owner of the store
    if (true === $isOwner) {
        ...

        /**
         * HERE IS THE PROBLEM
         * but I think I should use the same solution
         * I used to get Orders: a new query using the
         * Notifications repository.
         */
        $return['notifications'] = $store->getUnreadNotifications();

        ...
    }

    return $return;
}
```

The code of the `Store` Entity:

```
/**
 * Stores
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="stores")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="\AppBundle\Entity\StoreRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Store
{
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="NotificationStore", mappedBy="forStore")
     */
    private $notifications;

    public function __construct()
    {
        ...

        $this->notifications = new ArrayCollection();

        ...
    }

    ...

    /**
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getNotifications()
    {
        return $this->notifications;
    }

    ...
}
```

The code of the Notification Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
abstract class Notification
{
    ...

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="isRead", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $isRead = false;

    ...

    public function setIsRead($isRead = false)
    {
        $this->isRead = $isRead;

        return $this;
    }

    public function isRead()
    {
        return $this->isRead;
    }
}
```

The code of the NotificationStore Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="notifications_stores")
 */
class NotificationStore extends Notification
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Store", inversedBy="notifications")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="for_store", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $forStore;

    public function setForStore($forStore)
    {
        $this->forStore = $forStore;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getForStore()
    {
        return $this->code;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should create a custom repository classe.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But where have I to put the method? In the Store class or in the StoreNotification class? Maybe in the Store class? Is correct?

Comment: If you are okay with always loading all notifications then add the method to the Store entity.  Clean and simple.  However, if a typical store has lots of read notifications and you don't want to always load all of them then add a query to the repository as @scoolnico has suggested.  In this scenerio, the store would only have unread notifications and thus there would be no need for an additional get method.

Answer (score 1):

There are a two ways to deal with this situation:

1. Create a repository `StoreRepository` and retrieve the `Store` entity with by "joining" the `notifications` using a join which filters the notifications i.e.:

   ```
   class StoreRepository extends EntityRepository {
       public function findStoreWithNotifications($id) {
           return $this->createQueryBuilder('store')
               ->addSelect('notification')
               ->leftJoin('store.notifications', 'notification', 'WITH', 'notification.isRead IS false')
               ->where('store.id = :storeId')
               ->setParameter('storeId' => $id)
               ->getQuery()
               ->getSingleResult()
           ;
       }
   }
   ```

   Calling the `findStoreWithNotifications` method will return the `Store` entity and join all `Notifications`, filtered by the read status.
2. Create a `getUnreadNotifications` method in your `Store` entity and use [Doctrine Criteria](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections) to filter the notification collection. If you choose to use this approach, you should be **extremely** cautious because each time you call the `getUnreadNotifications` method a **new** query to the database will be triggered.

Which method you choose depends on your case.

Update based on the comments:

In your controller you have:

```
$store = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Store')->find($id);
```

With my purposed code this line would become:

```
$store = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Store')->findStoreWithNotifications($id);
```

Then in your `$return` variable, you would only do:

```
$return['notifications'] = $store->getNotifications();
```

Which will give you only the filtered *unread* notifications, because of the join in the `StoreRepository`.

Comment: I don't want to find all stores with notifications, but all notifications of a provided store.

So, if I'm seeing the page of "Store A", I want to list in this page all the notifications of the "Store A".

Comment: Well, the query above does exactly that? You pass the store `id` as a parameter and it fetches that `Store` with all associated unread notifications. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: I don't think a join is necessary as there is one-to-many relation between the notification and the store. So a store can have more than one notification, but a notification is only of one store. So in the notification table/entity I have a field `forStore`. Mmm... I'll think about this...

Comment: Anyway, I think the Criteria approach is the more correct, but I don't understand how to implement it in a Repository: can you provide me a basic example? I think this is the real solution!

Comment: Mmm, but they seem to be very complex and overpowerful for a scenario like this, where I have to simply do a select based on a single field with a single value (`isRead = 0 `).

Comment: I'm kind of lost with your comments. I don't seem to understand what is the problem? If you don't join the `notifications` and try to get them from the entity i.e. `Store->getNotifications()` a new query will be triggered which will fetch those records. If you, on the other hand, fetch the `Store` entity from `findStoreWithNotifications` you will make only *one* query to the database, which retrieves all the information you want. IMHO you should go with the code I posted above. Doctrine Criteria's are a bit complex and should be used in more specific cases.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I've updated the question adding also the code of the controller, so all should be more clear. Anyway, I think I need another query to only get notifications, the same way I do to get orders (see the controller I posted to understand what I saying).

Answer (score 0):

I would add the `getUnreadNotifications` method in the `Store` Entity like this:

```
/**
 * Stores
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="stores")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="\AppBundle\Entity\StoreRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Store
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @return ArrayCollection|Notification[]
     */
    public function getUnreadNotifications()
    {
        return $this->notifications->filter(function(Notification $notification) {
            return !$notification->isRead()
        });
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I want the UnreadNotifications, not all the notification (this method is yet present in the class). Where should have I to put the `getUnreadNotifications()`method, in the `Store` class or in the `Notification` class?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to post this answer as I hadn't finished yet! Editing now...

Comment: This approach can take considerably longer to process. What if the `notifications` collection contains thousands of records? Why make the database return all those results if you only need 2  and further more process all the records with php to filter the collection? :)

Comment: Yes, I agree with tftd: this way I always load all the notifications and then go through the array filtering out the ones not read. But I want to select directly from the database only the unread notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

```
// YourBundle/Entity/StoreRepository.php

/.../  

class StoreRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findByUnreadNotifications($id)
    {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
            ->where('s.id = :idStore')
            ->setParameter('idStore', $id)
            ->leftJoin('s.notifications', 'n')
            ->andwhere('n.isRead = :isRead')
            ->setParameter('isRead', false)
            ->getQuery()
        ;

        return $query->getResult();
    }
}
```

And in your controller:

```
/.../

$return['notifications'] = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Store')->findByUnreadNotifications($id);

/.../
```

Comment: This way I don't get a list of notifications, but get an array where each key has the store's info plus the notification info. So, if a store has 3 notifications, I have an array with three elements and each of them has the notification info but also the store info, hasn't it?

Comment: I've just edited the query: get the store in function of its ID and all the unread notifications of this one.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I added the method to the `NotificationRepository` class.
This makes a new query, but maintain the code more clear as the notification are get from the Notification Entity, without confusing purposes.

Thank you for all the replies! :)